# XML layout in tab android (tabhost)

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a tabbed layout working on android. Using an example I managed to get the tabs working but my different tabs are in different activities. Each tab is similar, it's almost the same so I want them in the same activity.

I want an xml file in the layout folder as content.

This works, seperate classes:

```
tabSpec1.setIndicator("tabName1").setContent(new Intent(this, FirstTab.class));
```

This doesn't work:

```
tabSpec2.setIndicator("tabName2").setContent(R.layout.tab);
```

The setContent function accepts id's like that. The reference to tab is also in my R class. This is the XML in my tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the tab from XML"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you mean by: "Each tab is similar, it's almost the same so I want them in the same activity."
Do you mean you want multiple instances of the same Activity in each tab?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error message or is it displaying blank?

Comment: @ Cephron I just want an XML layout into the tab. There are several reasons but I don't think it really matters

Comment: @James When I run it on my phone via usb-debugging it just won't start. Immediately I get an error the process has stopped

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? You'll find it in the DDMS view (top right corner) under the LogCat tab in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One way is to add a view like Cephron has shown in another answer.

Depending on how similar the tab activities are. Another way to do this would be to pass the intent to the same activity with different extras and then parse them in the Activity code.

Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstTab.class);
intent.putExtra("callingTab", 1);
tabSpec1.setIndicator("tabName1").setContent();
```

You activity code can then use something like this:

```
 if (FirstTab.this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
      callingTab = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("callingTab");
 }
```

This will allow you to use the same layout for both activities with the minor changes you require coded in.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [unable to add views in TabHost by IDs, crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837894/unable-to-add-views-in-tabhost-by-ids-crashing/4837969#4837969)

If you want to set content of each tab by View ids, you have to make sure that there is some layout xml that defines `TabHost`, `TabWidget`, and `FrameLayout` tags properly. Then the views that you want to be set by ids can be put as child tags in `FrameLayout`. Without any one of the tags mentioned above, the app will crash due to "cannot find view id xxxxxx".

You can get what you want by combining this and the `<include>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to have Views, not activities, in each tab. Try something like this...

In the tab activity:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_page_layout);

    //Setting up TabWidget
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("firstTab")
            .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.tab1_label), res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_icon))
            .setContent(R.id.tab1_layout);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("secondTab")
            .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.tab2_label), res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2_icon))
            .setContent(R.id.tab2_layout);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

In the tab_page_layout.xml file:

```
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1_layout"
        />
        <!--your stuff-->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab2_layout"
        />
        <!--your stuff-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

(The above is just a fragment, of course. You'll still need to include the TabWidget and use the appropriate identification)

Comment: Under where you have "<!--your stuff-->", is there a way to specify a layout xml? I did my layouts as separate xml layouts, now I just want to stick them into a tab.